# display number of rows found from data table in listview

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am  trying to display the number of rows in a listview. I tried this code but instead of working, it throws the error below. I am using mysql for a back end:

error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string " '" to type
>   'Double' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was
>   not in a correct format

VB Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            ViewState("Data") = ""
            Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM school")
                    Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
                        Using dt As New DataTable()
                            sda.Fill(dt)
                            ViewState("Data") = dt
                            schoollists.DataSource = dt
                            schoollists.DataBind()

                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            countResult.Text = (" '" + schoollists.Items.Count + "';")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: In VB.NET do not use the plus sign to concatenate string with numbers. Use the correct operator &

Comment: @Steve Please elaborate. I don't understand.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET using the `+ Operator` to concatenate a string and a number yields unexpected results (or better an exception as you can see)

Using `+` between a string and a number results in the attempt to convert the  string `" '"` (in your case) to a number and, of course, this will fail.

To be on the safe side, the correct operator to concatenate strings in VB.NET is the [& operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx)

```
countResult.Text = (" '" & schoollists.Items.Count & "';")
```

As a side note, this will happen because you have, in your project settings, the OPTION STRICT set to OFF. With this configuration the compiler cannot catch this problem and you cannot see the error until you hit it at runtime. I strongly suggest to set OPTION STRICT to ON also if, initially, you will have a lot of code to fix.

A detailed explanation of the behavior of the plus operator when used with numbers and strings is present in the REMARKS section of the [+ Operator on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx)